# Product2id not working for upsert in salesforce integration

Tags: apex, integration

As i tried with Upserting the Product2id in salesforce integration but its giving error field is read only. for upsert.

It works well for insert but not for upsert.

Do you any workaround for the same.?

Comment: What object are you trying to upsert?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the field Product2id, take a look at this documentation: [PricebookEntry](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_pricebookentry.htm).

> Description
>
> Required. ID of the Product2 record with which this record is
>   associated. This field must be specified when creating Product2
>   records. It can’t be changed in an update.

**Suggested workarounds:**

1. Create a new PricebookEntry with the same info except the Product2id, delete the old PricebookEntry and insert the new PricebookEntry copied.
2. Create a new custom field Product2__c and work with this field instead of the standard Product2, but this solution will involve more effort.